# How to reproduce the following matlab code involving for loop in R?

Tags: r, matlab, for-loop, plot

I want to plot a graph using a for loop in R. I have tried using matlab and it works without problem.

I have tried following code in matlab:

```matlab
# matlab code

d=0:400;
for h=1:10:50
w=1./(1+(d.^2/h^2));
plot(d,w);
hold on
end
xlabel('Distance(km)')
ylabel('Weight')
```

I tried the following code in R, however it does not seem to work

```r
# R code

h <- c(1,20,50,100,200,400)
d <- seq(40, 420, by = 20)
for (i in 1:d) {
  w <- 1/(1+(i^2/h^2))
  lines(d, w)
}
```

How can I reproduce the above matlab code in R using for loop?

Comment: this might be of interest for you: http://www.math.umaine.edu/~hiebeler/comp/matlabR.pdf. I dont have matlab installed. Is the output the same if i run the code here? https://octave-online.net/

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility using the Tidyverse packages:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- 
  tibble(
    d = rep(0:400, 5),
    h = rep(c(1, 11, 21, 31, 41), each = 401)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(w = 1 / (1 + (d ^ 2 / h ^ 2)))

df %>% 
  mutate(h = factor(h)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = d, y = w, color = h)) +
  geom_line() + 
  labs(
    x = "Distance (km)",
    y = "Weight"
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: I understand that R as different ways of ploting this graph, however i am particularly interested to do by for loop only. I just want to see the difference between matlab and R.